# How to set category mask in sprite kit?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

```
  let dart = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Dart")
        dart.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        dart.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 3
        dart.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 2
```

when I print the darts category masks it returns nil. I have set other sprites category masks through the scene editor and they work fine. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't actually made a physics body.

```swift
dart.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(...)
dart.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
// etc.
```

The ... depends on the type of physics body you want (circle, rectangle, polygon, etc.)  See examples here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/getting_started_with_physics_bodies